# Calling a method from C# on a templated C++/CLI base class

Tags: c#, templates, c++-cli

I have a class, **A**, in C++/CLI which derives from a templated base class, **B**.
I have some C# code that has an instance of **A** and wants to call a method on it.
If the method is implemented in **A** all is fine. If it's implemented in **B** things get strange.

I knocked up the simplest code that demonstrates what I am trying to do:

C++/ CLI:

`template<typename T>
public ref class B
{
public:
  void Test(){}
};`

public ref class A : public B<System::Int32>
{
};

C#:

  `A a = new A();
  a.Test();`

In this test code, the call to `Test()` doesn't compile (I get: "does not contain a definition for 'Test'"). I get the same result if I modify it to make `Test()` static (and call it on **A**, rather than the instance).  If that was the end of the story I would just shake my fist at Microsoft and live with it.

However, in my real code I have my equivalent to `Test()` working!
Bizarrely, it only works in one case. If I copy my working method and just change the name the new method is unreachable again.

To rule out the naming being picked up from elsewhere I tried removing the working method. The code now fails to build, as expected.

I'm guessing that what I am seeing, still, is a glitch and that I what I am trying to do is not supported. But since I can't find any references that rule it out, and with the anomaly I'm seeing, I'd like to know for certain what I should be expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain C++, templated class methods are only instantiated if they are actually used within the linkage scope.  I suspect that the C++/CLI implementation may be doing the equivalent -- not generating code for Test() if it's not being used in the C++ assembly.

Comment: That's why I love stackoverflow :-) This is *exactly* what's happening. So obvious when you think about it. I can work around it now. Thanks for your swift answer.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is actually very simple. When you compile your mixed assembly - C++/CLI there are some rules that the compiler follows to exporting native functions outside the assembly and outputting meta data for them.

One of them is that native methods don't get exposed out of the assembly unless explicitly specified. To explicitly specify a native method to be exposed via meta data, you use the `#pragma make_public( Your Class Here )`.

Other one is that template functions cannot be exposed out of the assembly. So in your case you can't expose the template class.

BUT in your case I am almost positive that you don't need template class, but a generic one which is absolutely OK to be exported.

Why do you need templates? Do you understand the difference between template<> and generic<>? One is compile time unit, the other is runtime.

Try using

```
generic<class T>
public ref class B
{
public:
  void Test(){}
};


public ref class A : public B<System::Int32>
{
};
```

Comment: There are no native methods in his code. Both classes are `ref`, so all code is managed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Ivan. Obviously the example is not representative of what I am trying to do with the templates. I am using a template here specifically to get compile time results. I can't achieve the same thing with generics. It seems the accepted answer was all I needed to get this working.